# Send push notifications dynamically with parse.com

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm making an app that is a news portal, my client wants certain materials are sent via PUSH notifications.

There is the possibility to send notifications via dynamic "code" without using the interface [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/)?

Example: A news reaches 10,000 views, this time I shoot a notification to users who use the app automatically, without any interaction.

Is this possible? If you are unable to parse.com, is there any other service that I can use?

Thank you!

Comment: are you asking what push services are available?

Comment: No, I was asking if it was possible to send a notification using the api parse.com without using their submission interface in case I send the notification of a dynamic way, but I found what I wanted on this link:https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications I can send notification via POST using curl

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible....
just use their cloud code SDK and see the push notification section here
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications

the methods declared in cloud code can be accessed from apps native code